# How to set WriteConcern globally for embedded mongo (flapdoodle) to fix intermittent test failures

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, embedded-database

**Question: Is there a way to change the config for (Flapdoodle) embedded mongo so that I can guarantee writes happen before reads?** Please note the question is specifically about Flapdoodle's implementation, rather than MongoDB in general. I only want to apply this in test and in config (if possible) rather than go through all my Mongo Operations and set the write concerns everywhere.

**Details**

I'm using Spring + embedded mongo in my testing environment. Maven dependency looks like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.50.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

With a test config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "path.to.repos")
public class TestMongoConfig {
private static final String DESTROY_METHOD_CLOSE = "close";
private static final String DESTROY_METHOD_STOP = "stop";

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestMongoConfig.class);

@Autowired
private MongoProperties mongoProperties;

@Autowired(required = false)
private MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions;

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean(destroyMethod = DESTROY_METHOD_CLOSE)
public MongoClient mongo() throws IOException {
    Net net = mongodProcess().getConfig().net();
    mongoProperties.setHost(net.getServerAddress().getHostName());
    mongoProperties.setPort(net.getPort());
    return mongoProperties.createMongoClient(this.mongoClientOptions, environment);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = DESTROY_METHOD_STOP)
public MongodProcess mongodProcess() throws IOException {
    return mongodExecutable().start();
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = DESTROY_METHOD_STOP)
public MongodExecutable mongodExecutable() throws IOException {
    return mongodStarter().prepare(mongodConfig());
}

@Bean
public IMongodConfig mongodConfig() throws IOException {
    return new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION).build();
}

@Bean
public MongodStarter mongodStarter() {
    Command command = Command.MongoD;
    IRuntimeConfig runtimeConfig = new RuntimeConfigBuilder()
            .defaultsWithLogger(command, LOGGER)
            .artifactStore(new ExtractedArtifactStoreBuilder()
                    .defaults(command)
                    .download(new DownloadConfigBuilder()
                            .defaultsForCommand(command).build())
                    .executableNaming(new UserTempNaming()))
            .build();

    return MongodStarter.getInstance(runtimeConfig);
}
```

In that class its pretty standard, just following flapdoodle's examples.

95% of the time this works great, all my tests pass. Intermittently some random tests fail, e.g. when I do something like this:

```
userRepository.customMethodPushToList(user.getId(), aString);
user = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());
assertEquals(2, user.getSomeList().size());
```

All `customMethodPushToList` is doing is pushing a string to a list in the `User` entry in the database. Nothing special here. However 5% of the time the test fails.

I *think* it's because something to do with write concern... i.e. I've retrieved the object before it's been updated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After answer from a poster, I've created `MongoClientOperations` manually:

```
MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED).build();
```

So far so good...

Comment: are you using the embeed mongo or real mongo instance for testing?
I am facing an issue with embeed mongo it was using the real monogo instance.
thanks in advance.

Comment: @devanathan no there was no other instance of Mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to use after you get a DB (with getDatabase()) is withWriteConcern():
http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoDatabase.html#withWriteConcern-com.mongodb.WriteConcern-

And use ACKNOWLEDGED:
http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#ACKNOWLEDGED

Also use withReadPreference()
http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoDatabase.html#withReadPreference-com.mongodb.ReadPreference-

And use primary():
http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html#primary--

This will make the behavior as trivial as it can be.

Comment: Thanks, however its not clear how I get a reference to the DB itself from the `TestConfig`? `MongoClientOptions` seems to be immutable, otherwise that has a `WriteConcern` option

Comment: Instead of autowiring MongoClientOptions, I have put `MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().writeConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED).build();`

Comment: @user2393012 If you still want to use `@Autowired` you can use a method with `@Bean` annotation that creates the `MongoClientOptions`.